# How to mark a card good/bad via JavaScript?

Tags: anki

Can you think of how to mark a card good/bad via Javascript, so it marks the current card and then displays the next one?

Ideally without any addons so it works on mobiles.

I am creating a custom quiz interface with multiple answer buttons.

Thank you!

Comment: Using Flags should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Turns out it is already available in the AnkiDroid
https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/wiki/Advanced-formatting#designing-custom-cards-layout-for-buttons

```
showAnswer()
buttonAnswerEase1()
buttonAnswerEase2()
buttonAnswerEase3()
buttonAnswerEase4()
ankiMarkCard()
ankiToggleFlag()
AnkiDroidJS.ankiGetNewCardCount()
AnkiDroidJS.ankiGetLrnCardCount()
AnkiDroidJS.ankiGetRevCardCount()
AnkiDroidJS.ankiGetCardMark()
AnkiDroidJS.ankiGetCardFlag()
AnkiDroidJS.ankiGetETA()
```

In the next release they are planning to implement JS function to get the time for each button (to find out which one is "good" and if "easy" is available.